# redirect to interior page relating to window width

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile, window.location

So I'm in the process of creating a mobile web site but I'm wanting it to redirect my home page to an interior page depending on if the user is on a mobile phone

This is what I have in the head of my index.html

```
<script>

    $(window).ready(function(){
        function() {
            if( window.width <= 770 ){
                window.location = "http://dylanstewartcreative.com/print.html"
                } else {
                    window.location = "http://dylanstewartcreative.com/index.html"
                    }
            }       
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are these two pages showing the same/similar information?

Comment: Try `$(window).load` that event will be never fired.

Comment: no my index.html is literally three links leading to other interior pages and the print.html is the lading page for my portfolio

Comment: Yeah Idipaolo i tried adding the $(window).load and it spazzed out my home page when i refreshed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Note, you only need to determine what will happen if the screen size is less that what you determine. If this criteria is not met (ie. screen size is larger) then nothing happens.

Place this in the head of your index.html file

```
<script>
<!--//
if (screen.width <= 534) {
document.location = "/Mobile/";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Also, don't forget to put this in your head, preferably just above your title tag grouped with similar meta tags.

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```